# MDX Calculated Member - Total Order Amount from any Order Line

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse

I have a requirement for a cube that I find basic but I struggle to find a solution to it.

I have an **Order Fact**, an **Order Line Fact** and a **Product Dimension**.

- **Order Fact** contains the different amounts for the order
- **Order Line Fact** contains the different amounts for a particular line of an order, this is where we find the key to the **Product Dimension**

When a *Product Category* is selected, I need to be able to return from the **Order Line Fact** (because only this table has a link to **Product Dimension**) the total amount of the **Order Fact** for each order line that has a match on the *Product Category*.

For example :

```
Order 1 -> 100$
Order 1, Line 1 : Category FOO -> 30$
Order 1, Line 2 : Category BAR -> 20$
Order 1, Line 3 : Category FOO -> 50$

Order 2 -> 45$
Order 2, Line 1 : Category FOO -> 45$
```

If I do a simple query like the following should return me 100$ :

```
SELECT
  [Measures].[X] ON 0,
  [Product].[Category].&[BAR] ON 1
FROM Cube
```

And querying the FOO category should return 145$ :

```
SELECT
  [Measures].[X] ON 0,
  [Product].[Category].&[FOO] ON 1
FROM Cube
```

So I need to link my Orders to the Products in some way in link my Order Lines to my Orders. I have added the *Order Amount* and *Order Number* to each **Order Line Fact** but I'm lost as to how I can use them with a calculated member to fulfill my need.

Comment: From what I have seen with the cubes I work on, the Order/OrderLine is flattened to one fact table, and the Cube deals with aggregations at the order/customer/rep etc levels for that fact.

Comment: You can have an order fact and an order line fact, but you should only have the order fact if there is something that exists at that level of granularity that doesn't exist at order line. If you have a calculated measure, you just have to make sure the measures used in that calculation are properly related in the dimension usage.

Comment: @TimothyWalters is right lines and headers in cubes are aggregated

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can approach this. Either way, I'm not seeing where you need a calculated member to meet your needs. They happen to have this exact scenario in the AdventureWorks 2012 Multidimensional Cube.

They have one Sales Order dimension that includes both the order number and order line. They have these as individual hierarchies and they put them together in a user hierarchy as well. 
Then they created a single Sales Order measure group for the amount (at the order line level). They related this to both the Sales Order Dimension and the Product Dimension. This allows you to get the total for the order or the total for a specific product category.

You can download the AdventureWorks 2012 MD cube [here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330) and take a look for yourself.

Comment: You are right, they have the Internet Sales, the Reseller Sales and they made a Sales Summary and generated Degenerated Dimensions from facts (which are order line level) to be able to aggregate their data for the Order Level. But if you want Adventure works to return the Total Sales Amount from all sales containing Product X, there's no way of doing it cleanly without (if even possible... but I hope so) using a Calculated Member. Because simply asking "Select TotalSale ON 0 FROM Cube WHERE Product.X" will only give the Amount for the lines containing the product and not the Sales Amount.

Comment: Isolate your analysis to just Internet Sales. There is an Internet Sales Order Details dimension that contains both the order and order line. That is tied to the Internet Sales measure group. This is similar to what you are looking for. You can use the internet sales amount fact to get the total sales across all orders and product categories.

Comment: I have a hard time explaining... If you refer to my example Data. If I do the "SELECT [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON 0, [Product].[Category].&[FOO] ON 1 FROM Cube", it will return 125$ because the sales amount linked to the FOO category is 125$. But what I want is 145$. I have no problem reproducing the structure of Adventure Works from my data, but it doesn't contain the Measure I need to get the Total Order Sales of all Orders containing ONE OR MANY line of a specified product. But I know all the tools are there but I can't figure out how to get it.

Comment: So you want a calculated measure that returns the total for all orders that contain a product from category Foo?

Comment: @Nick - did you ever manage to work this out?  I'm having a similar problem right now and struggling to find the answer